# How do store an array of emails in Core Data and Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I am new to Core Data as well as Magical Record. I have a JSON like so :

```
{user:{emails:["a@b.com","c@d.com"]}}
```

I was initially planning to store the "emails" field as string and convert to real emails on retrieve but while importing the json using MagicalImport, I get the following error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "invitedEmail"; desired type = NSString; given type = __NSArrayI; value = (

I can keep the "emails" attribute to be string and while storing manually convert the "emails" array json to string but that seems like a hack. There has to be a cleaner way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hack or not, putting your emails into a comma delimited string might be the way to go here as you can't store arrays in core data.

The other option is to make a second entity for emails (and maybe anything else that has a many-to-one type relationship) and then give it a relationship to your user entity, but there's probably no reason to. I would just store it as a comma delimited string and call it a day.

Comment: Any data type that conforms to nscoding can be stored in core data as a transformable attribute. Since you are using an array of strings, this is easily doable. I would, however recommend against this, and instead have a single entity with an email field (as a string) to which you can search filter and sort against.

Comment: Agreed. Possible, but not a good solution for this instance. You'd have to spend cycles coding and decoding it and as you said you lose the ability to query against it. The transformable attribute definitely has applicable circumstances, this just isn't one.